# Firebase Storage Error when upload file

Tags: firebase-storage

I try to upload images to firebase, but i always receive this exception[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRKKf.png)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Firebase Storage buckets require [Firebase Authentication](http://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to upload files. You can change your [Firebase Storage Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample_rules) to allow unauthenticated access.

Something like:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-firbase-storage-bucket>/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Will get you up and running ASAP